# min / max corners for 8 cubes forming a single cube around an origin

Tags: math, vector, gdscript

This is a more generic math / code question, in my case I need it for Godot / GDScript. I have a virtual cube defined as an origin point with a thickness offset, I loop through its mins and maxs on each axis to preform actions per unit. The normal cube is thus represented as:

```
const org = Vector3(32, 48, 64)
const thick = 16
const mins = Vector3(org.x - thick, org.y - thick, org.z - thick)
const maxs = Vector3(org.x + thick, org.y + thick, org.z + thick)

for x in range(mins.x, maxs.x, thick):
    for y in range(mins.y, maxs.y, thick):
        for z in range(mins.z, maxs.z, thick):
            var vec = Vector3(x, y, z)
```

What happens is I want to subdivide this cube into 8 cubes perfectly touching each other. I need to have a `mins_0` / `maxs_0`, `mins_1` / `maxs_1`,  ... , `mins_7` / `maxs_7` each representing a section of the cube.

I'm stuck on the math: I don't know how to transpose the origin and thickness offsets, obviously keeping the order so that any loop starts from the proper location (`mins.# < maxs.#` always). I only know two of the combinations which are obvious:

```
mins_0 = Vector3(org.x - thick, org.y - thick, org.z - thick)
maxs_0 = Vector3(org.x, org.y, org.z)
mins_4 = Vector3(org.x, org.y, org.z)
maxs_4 = Vector3(org.x + thick, org.y + thick, org.z + thick)
```

How do I fill the other 6 spaces in proper order to cover the remaining area?

Comment: I don't know `gdscript`; can you use basic vector arithmetic, adding and subtracting vectors?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tKWeh9GY Represented my question into JavaScript with the vector as an object. I believe I need to work with the X Y Z values independently, combining them to or from a vector shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: With the loop presented in the question, did you meant to iterate over the corners of the cube? Or did you mean to iterate over over middle points too? Regardless, I don't think the loop does what you wanted it to do. For example, with `for x in range(mins.x, maxs.x, thick):` the variable `x` will not be equal to `maxs.x`. You will get two iterations: in one `x` equals `mins.x` and on the other it advances `thick` which gives you `x` equals `org.x`. There is no third iteration because for it `x` would have to be equal to `maxs.x` but `range` is exclusive on the upper bound.

Comment: Oh. My code does what I intend it to (marching cubes chunk generation) but I think I noticed that on the + axis one chunk is skipped: I probably need to add an extra chunk to the end point for the scan to work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a *lot* simpler with vector arithmetic, but we can do it with the raw coordinates:

```
mins_0 = Vector3(org.x - thick, org.y - thick, org.z - thick)
maxs_0 = Vector3(org.x,         org.y,         org.z)

mins_1 = Vector3(org.x - thick, org.y - thick, org.z)
maxs_1 = Vector3(org.x,         org.y,         org.z + thick)

mins_2 = Vector3(org.x - thick, org.y,         org.z - thick)
maxs_2 = Vector3(org.x,         org.y + thick, org.z)

mins_3 = Vector3(org.x - thick, org.y,         org.z)
maxs_3 = Vector3(org.x,         org.y + thick, org.z + thick)

mins_4 = Vector3(org.x,         org.y - thick, org.z - thick)
maxs_4 = Vector3(org.x + thick, org.y,         org.z)

mins_5 = Vector3(org.x,         org.y - thick, org.z)
maxs_5 = Vector3(org.x + thick, org.y,         org.z + thick)

mins_6 = Vector3(org.x,         org.y,         org.z - thick)
maxs_6 = Vector3(org.x + thick, org.y + thick, org.z)

mins_7 = Vector3(org.x,         org.y,         org.z)
maxs_7 = Vector3(org.x + thick, org.y + thick, org.z + thick)
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thank you. I can probably do it with vector arithmetic too, if there's an answer to that feel free to share.